# The 'pluginOptions["url"]' property has not been set

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I have a problem with `Kartik/DepDrop`. I have used it many times in the past but are now having an issue

My view

```
 'contentBefore'=>'<legend class="text-info"><small>Client Info</small></legend>',
                'attributes'=>[       // 2 column layout
                    'model'=>['type'=>Form::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST, 'items'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Models::find()->All(), 'id','name'), 'options'=>['prompt'=>'Please Select..','id'=>'model']],
                    'field'=>[
                        'type'=>Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 
                        'widgetClass'=>DepDrop::classname(),
                        'options' => ['id'=>'field'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'depends'  => ['model'],
                            'placeholder' => 'select ...',
                            'url' => Url::to(['dd-field'])
                        ],
                    ],
                    'related_value'=>['type'=>Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Enter Value...']],
                ]
```

And the error shows this

```
_form.php at line 49 – yii\base\Widget::widget(['model' => app\models\RelatedFields, 'form' => kartik\form\ActiveForm, 'autoGenerateColumns' => true, 'rows' => [['contentBefore' => '<legend class="text-info"><small...', 'attributes' => ['model' => ['type' => 'dropdownList', 'items' => [1 => 'Clients', 2 => 'InvoiceItems', 3 => 'Invoices', 4 => 'Notes', ...], 'options' => ['prompt' => 'Please Select..', 'id' => 'model']], 'field' => ['type' => 'widget', 'widgetClass' => 'kartik\depdrop\DepDrop', 'options' => ['id' => 'field'], 'pluginOptions' => ['depends' => ['model'], 'placeholder' => 'select ...', 'url' => '/related-fields/dd-field']], 'related_value' => ['type' => 'textInput', 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Value...']]]], ['attributes' => ['actions' => ['type' => 'raw', 'value' => '<div style="text-align: right; m...']]]], ...])
```

If you look at the plugin options it is being passed

```
'pluginOptions' => ['depends' => ['model'], 'placeholder' => 'select ...', 'url' => '/related-fields/dd-field']
```

Any ideas anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, as i am using `FormGrid`, the `pluginOptions` and `htmlOptions` all need to be inside an options array like this

```
'field'=>[
    'type'=>Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 
    'widgetClass'=>DepDrop::classname(),
    'options' => [
        'options'=> ['id' => 'field'], 
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'depends' => ['model'], 
            'placeholder' => 'select ...', 
            'url' => '/related-fields/dd-field'
        ],
    ],
],
```